# Tomcat 8.5 logging not ignoring class

Tags: java, logging, tomcat8, java.util.logging

So I'm trying to filter out a WARNING level message from our tomcat logs. The warning is:

`[ajp-nio-8020-exec-5] [com.sun.xml.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector] .selectAlternatives WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext}SecurityToken" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".`

I've tried updating logging.properties within tomcat to add:

`com.sun.xml.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector.level = OFF`

Despite that the warning keeps showing. So far the only thing I could do to shut it up is to turn the java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = OFF, which is obviously not ideal.

We are running a vanilla logging.properties file from Tomcat 8.5 why isn't the simple class log level = off working?

Complete snippet:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter


org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

com.sun.xml.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector.level = OFF
```

Comment: The logger name might not be the same as the class name.  Alter the [format pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) to include the logger name and the class name.  Then retest using the new format.

Comment: Ahhhh thanks. It looks like the logger was com.sun.xml.ws.wspolicy and not com.sun.xml.ws.policy. Has me scratching my head a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As jmehrens pointed out the logger name was in fact different. The source was com.sun.xml.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector, but the logger name was com.sun.xml.ws.wspolicy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector. One I updated the name in logging.properties it worked like a charm. Thanks, jmehrens!